# Not printing the array correctly when reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge

i have 1 javascript array. i wanted to merge this array based on the dates and get each of the price and put in the field. However the price im only getting is 1. the other price with the same date is not printing. Can anyone help me why ? Thank you

Here is the code:

Javascript:

```
var data = [
   {
      "date":"2010-01-01",
      "name":"a"
   },
   {
      "date":"2010-02-01",
      "name":"b"
   },
   {
      "date":"2010-03-01",
      "name":"c"
   },
   {
      "date":"2010-01-01",
      "name":"aa"
   },
   
]

var result1 = data.reduce((p, c) => 
  (p[c.date] = Object.assign({},{name: null}, p[c.date], c)) && p
  , {});

var final = Object.keys(result1).map(x=>result1[x])

console.log(final)
```

You can access the code here:

https://jsfiddle.net/q0wn2vuo/

I want the output like this:

[{
date: "2010-01-01",
name: 'a,aa',
}, {
date: "2010-02-01",
name: 'b',
}, {
date: "2010-03-01",
price: 'c',
}]

Comment: What do you mean by `price: 30 45`? That's not valid syntax, do you want `[30, 45]`, or `'30 45'` or something?

Comment: sorry '30,45' thats the output i want

Comment: So you require strings when the prices are combined, but numbers otherwise? (sounds a bit odd)

Comment: this data is sample only. i want to combined the name of the data actually. wait let me edit the code first. sorrryyy

Comment: i already edit my post. very sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Here you go.

```js
var data = [
   {
  "date":"2010-01-01",
  "name":"a"
   },
   {
  "date":"2010-02-01",
  "name":"b"
   },
   {
  "date":"2010-03-01",
  "name":"c"
   },
   {
  "date":"2010-01-01",
  "name":"aa"
   },
   
]

const resultSet = {};

 for (let i = 0, _len = data.length; i < _len; i++ ) {
       if(resultSet[data[i].date]){
        resultSet[data[i].date] += ","+data[i].name
       }
       else{
        resultSet[data[i].date] = data[i].name
       }
       
    }

const resultArr = Object.entries(resultSet).map(([key,value])=>{
 return { date: key, name: value }
})
console.log(resultArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```js
var data = [
   {
      "date":"2010-01-01",
      "name":"a"
   },
   {
      "date":"2010-02-01",
      "name":"b"
   },
   {
      "date":"2010-03-01",
      "name":"c"
   },
   {
      "date":"2010-01-01",
      "name":"aa"
   },  
]


var result1 = data.reduce((accum, curr) => {
  if (!accum[curr.date]) {
    return {...accum, [curr.date]: [curr.name] }
  }
  return {...accum, [curr.date]: [...accum[curr.date], curr.name] }
}, {})

var final = Object.keys(result1).map(date => ({
  date: date,
  name: result1[date].join(',')
}))

console.log(final)
```